# containsLocation not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to retrieve a boolean result using 'google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation', the problem is than isnt returning nothing, I don't know if I need to called it inside of a eventListener, but when I try to called it starts saying that 'pos' is undefined, then when I intialize pos, it says that "lng" is not defined, something is wrong with my code or I'm not doing it the right way.

JS:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.185083, lng: -8.698814},
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };


      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are Here.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }



   // Define the LatLng coordinates for Zone.
  var zone_Coords = [
    {lat: 41.194975, lng: -8.683102},
    {lat: 41.183693, lng: -8.703740},
    {lat: 41.205572, lng: -8.717563},
    {lat: 41.203185, lng: -8.690135},
    {lat: 41.194975, lng: -8.683102}
  ];

   // Construct the Zone.
  var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone_Coords,
    strokeColor: '#023bca',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0748eb',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  zone3.setMap(map);

var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos, zone);
    console.log(isWithinPolygon);

}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geolocation service is asynchronous, you need to use the position in the callback function where/when it is available.

```
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };


      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are Here.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
      // the containsLocation method requires a google.maps.LatLng as the first arg
      var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng), zone);
      console.log(isWithinPolygon);
   // ...
```

Another issue with your code is the `containsLocation method requires a google.maps.LatLng as the "point", you can't use a google.maps.LatLngLiteral there.

from [the documentation:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

> containsLocation(point:**LatLng**, polygon:Polygon) | Return Value:  boolean

> Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

```
// the containsLocation method requires a google.maps.LatLng as the first arg
var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng), zone);
console.log(isWithinPolygon);
```

(**the above is no longer true, the documentation has been updated to reflect that the `containsLocation` method now accepts a `LatLngLiteral`**)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/43ss0frs/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 41.185083,
      lng: -8.698814
    },
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map
  });
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };


      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are Here.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
      // the containsLocation method requires a google.maps.LatLng as the first arg
      var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng), zone);
      console.log(isWithinPolygon);


    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }



  // Define the LatLng coordinates for Zone.
  var zone_Coords = [{
    lat: 41.194975,
    lng: -8.683102
  }, {
    lat: 41.183693,
    lng: -8.703740
  }, {
    lat: 41.205572,
    lng: -8.717563
  }, {
    lat: 41.203185,
    lng: -8.690135
  }, {
    lat: 41.194975,
    lng: -8.683102
  }];

  // Construct the Zone.
  var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone_Coords,
    strokeColor: '#023bca',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0748eb',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  zone.setMap(map);
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Please check the reference again - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly. It says that point can be LatLng or LatLngLiteral.

Comment: That wasn't true when this answer was written.